# Excel - How to find a number exist in which sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 10 sheets in a excel file.
Sheet2 to Sheet10 are raw data, and every sheet A1 has that sheet name, like this

Sheet2

```
        colA    colB    colC    colD
row1    Sheet2              
row2            489     154     785
row3            588     256     546
row4            758     654     945
```

Sheet3

```
        colA    colB    colC    colD
row1    Sheet3              
row2            758     95      245
row3            236     265     956
row4            879     486     785
```

In Sheet1, I found the max value of each cell across all sheet like below.
It only give me the value, and I also want to know this value is from which sheet.
So I do it like this `=INDEX(Sheet2:Sheet10!A1,MATCH(A1,Sheet2:Sheet10!B2,0))`, but return `#VALUE!`.

```
        colA                    colB                    colC
row1    =MAX(Sheet2:Sheet10!B2) =MAX(Sheet2:Sheet10!C2) ...
row2    =MAX(Sheet2:Sheet10!B3) =MAX(Sheet2:Sheet10!C3)
row3    ...
```

What I expected should like this

```
        colA    colB    colC    colD
row1    758                     Sheet3 (mean A1 max value 758 is from Sheet3)
row2    588     ...             Sheet2 (mean A2 max value 588 is from Sheet2)
row3    879
```

How should I change my formula?

Comment: Please add a screenshot from you excel sheets, and clarify what you exactly want to search for?

Comment: @Sanu_012 I updated my question, hope you are more clear what I want to get. I already know 758 is the max value of cell B2 across all Sheet2 to 10, but I can only know the value is 758, and I also want to know value 758 is from which sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if below solution works for you with a Helper Column. To keep it simple I am just using  three Sheets, Sheet2, Sheet3 & Sheet4

[image]

Above is sample data in Sheet2, Sheet3 & Sheet4

In your main sheet Sheet1 at a corner create a Helper column and put the names of all sheets therein (Exclude the very first sheet name in that list).

See the below screenshot.

[image]

In this example I have created Helper Column K. K1:K3 holds sheet names with your raw data.

Formula in B2, you are already using.

```
=MAX(Sheet2:Sheet4!B2)
```

Drag it across rows and columns to get the respective MAX values.

Now in E2 Put the following formula and from within the Formula Bar press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create an Array Formula. Curly braces shall get automatically added to the formula to make it an Array Formula.

```
=INDEX($K$1:$K$3,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT($K$1:$K$3&"!"&CELL("address",B2)),B2),0))
```

Drag it down along the rows & column cells down & across respectively to get the sheet name where MAX value is located.

Note that this does not factor in duplicate MAX values. If they exist, the first MATCH sheet name will be returned.

Also the position of sheets is important. The helper column list should be in the same order(position) as that of the raw data sheets and if you switch the position of actual raw data sheets later, the solution will not report the sheet name correctly.

Hope this helps.